Woocommerce - display products based on count from another table
On my woocommerce store, I have products that are auctions. Users have the ability to 'add to watchlist' any auction product.  This watchlist item is then stored as an id number in the "_auction_watch" field of a table called "usermeta".  It is simply stored as a digit, which is the id number.
I want to display a section on a page using a php snippet I called "Most Watched Items".
I came up with the below code to choose and count the number of product IDs from the usermeta table.  However, now I need to know how to then display those products. I got lost on how to join and/or bring up the image, title and permalink data from the products table to create the results display.
My code below returns the results but doesn't even display it as text or anything, because I wasn't sure how to do it. I merely got this far to count the number of watched items.
<?php
/**
 * Retrieves the most watched auctions and their total quantities.
 *
 * @return array An associative array with the following keys:
 *               - '_auction_watch': The auction ID.
 *               - 'MostWatched': The total quantity of the auction.
 */
function getMostWatchedAuctions() {
    global $wpdb;

    $query = " 
        SELECT
            _auction_watch,
            SUM(quantity) AS MostWatched
        FROM
            {$wpdb->prefix}usermeta
        GROUP BY
            _auction_watch
        ORDER BY
            MostWatched
        DESC
    ";

    $results = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);

    return $results;
}

Now, how do I return the results using the information in the products table? (like image, title, permalink). Thank you!

Here is my opinion.
 <?php
/**
 * Retrieves the most watched auctions and their total quantities.
 *
 * @return array An associative array with auction details.
 */
function getMostWatchedAuctions() {
    global $wpdb;

    // Query to get the most watched auction IDs and their counts
    $query = "
        SELECT
            um.meta_value AS auction_id,
            COUNT(*) AS MostWatched
        FROM
            {$wpdb->prefix}usermeta um
        WHERE
            um.meta_key = '_auction_watch'
        GROUP BY
            um.meta_value
        ORDER BY
            MostWatched DESC
    ";

    // Get the results
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);

    // Get the product details for each auction ID
    $auctions = [];
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $auction_id = $result['auction_id'];
        $product = wc_get_product($auction_id);

        if ($product) {
            $auctions[] = [
                'ID' => $auction_id,
                'title' => $product->get_name(),
                'permalink' => get_permalink($auction_id),
                'image' => wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($auction_id), 'thumbnail')[0],
                'MostWatched' => $result['MostWatched']
            ];
        }
    }

    return $auctions;
}

/**
 * Display the most watched auctions.
 */
function displayMostWatchedAuctions() {
    $auctions = getMostWatchedAuctions();

    if (!empty($auctions)) {
        echo '<ul class="most-watched-auctions">';
        foreach ($auctions as $auction) {
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<a href="' . esc_url($auction['permalink']) . '">';
            echo '<img src="' . esc_url($auction['image']) . '" alt="' . esc_attr($auction['title']) . '">';
            echo '<h2>' . esc_html($auction['title']) . '</h2>';
            echo '</a>';
            echo '<p>Watch count: ' . esc_html($auction['MostWatched']) . '</p>';
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>No watched auctions found.</p>';
    }
}

// Use the function where you want to display the most watched auctions
displayMostWatchedAuctions();

That's all.
Thank you!

Thank you!  I will try this out, see if I don't mess it up and let you know... or ask more questions!

Alright, the query seems to have thrown no errors. Now, to get it to display I need to format a loop. Here is a sample loop. How would I incorporate your query into this loop?
`
 'product',
   'posts_per_page' => 12
   );
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
   while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
   endwhile;
  } else {
   echo __( 'No products found' );
  }
  wp_reset_postdata();
 ?>
`